# Why scrum v3 version(3.0.4281.00) is not reflecting as process template on tfs 2010

Tags: tfs-process-template

We have installed scrum v3 on server. Previously we had scrum v2 working fine on tfs 2008, but we upgraded tfs 2008 to tfs 2010. we have some issues with scrum v2 running on tfs 2010. but my concern is scrum v3 not visible as template when we create team project. I [read on this site](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/crispinparker/archive/2010/02/26/scrum-for-team-system-v3-release-candidate.aspx) :

> SfTS v3 Beta 2 and SfTS v2.x (TFS 2008) cannot coexist in a single TFS 2010 instance.

can this be a problem if yes, do i have to uninstall/delete scrum v2.

Comment: Which "Scrum v3" are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

In order to have a process template visible in the team project creation you need to upload the template first. See Team -> Team Project Collection-> Process Template manager to upload a template.